# Erroneous MissingOutputException errors on Google Cloud/Kubernetes

Tags: snakemake

Executing snakemake with `--kubernetes` on GCP I am running into erroneous `MissingeOutputException` errors. Looking at the logs it seems that the jobs ended successfully and the output files were successfully uploaded to the bucket. The reported missing files appear to be intact and look as expected. Unfortunately I have not been able to reliably recreate this issue so its difficult to determine what the cause may be. I have tried increasing `--latency-wait` to 900 with no help

Would appreciate any insight on how Snakemake determines what files may be missing as that seems to be the best place to start. Digging through the source code myself I could not quite figure it out.

Edit 2/23/22, adding example rule:

```
rule dedup:
    input:
        get_bams_for_dedup
    output:
        dedupBam = config['output'] + "{Organism}/{refGenome}/" + config['bamDir'] + "{sample}" + config['bam_suffix'],
        dedupBai = config['output'] + "{Organism}/{refGenome}/" + config['bamDir'] + "{sample}" + "_final.bam.bai",
    conda:
        "../envs/sambamba.yml"
    resources:
        threads = res_config['dedup']['threads'],
        mem_mb = lambda wildcards, attempt: attempt * res_config['dedup']['mem']
    log:
        "logs/{Organism}/dedup/{refGenome}_{sample}.txt"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/{Organism}/dedup/{refGenome}_{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "sambamba markdup -t {threads} {input} {output.dedupBam} 2> {log}"
```

This issue also leads to an IncompleteFilesException when trying to restart the workflow. Which doesn't make sense, as when Snakemake is run on kubernetes, the output file is uploaded to a bucket when the job finishes. And because the output files are in the bucket that means that the job must have completed successfully.

There seems to be something going on with how Snakemake is determining if an output file in the bucket is 'incomplete' I imagine it may have to do with the timestamps of the file vs the timestamps of when the Kubernetes job to create said file was submitted? I'm not sure though. Would appreciate feedback.

Comment: It would help to know how you define the rules that lead to this behaviour.

Comment: 99% of the time this happens to me is that I incorrectly define the output of my rule (typo in the path or file name). The files are created correctly but snakemake does not see them ;).

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev, I have edited my post to include an example rule.

Comment: @EricC., I wish this was the issue. I have checked many times. The workflow also runs fine locally, so this issue only occurs on GCP w/ Kubernetes to my knowledge.

Comment: @CadeM is your bai file created by the rule? Not sure sambamba creates this index file and if it does, wouldn't it have the same name as the bam file with '.bai' suffix? You seem to specify two different notations in your outputs.

Comment: @EricC. The outputs are named correctly and I can find the outputs in the google bucket named properly. Also this issue is not limited to this rule, but all of the rules in the workflow. The errors are also inconsistent, some instances of a rule finish fine, while others finish, but the output is marked as missing despite the output being present on the bucket. Thus, I believe the issue is related to how snakemake is checking the remote output.